# AutoMapper postfix not recognized

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper v9, and wish to have a postfix on my DTO property names of `Dto`.

In my profile I add:

```cs
RecognizeDestinationPostfixes("Dto");
```

I validate my mapping with `config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` and immediately it throws with

```
Unmapped properties:
AccountConnectionIdDto
CreatedDateDto
ModifiedDateDto
IdentityIdDto
AccountIdDto
```

This is what my DTO looks like:

```cs
public class AccountConnectionDto
{
    public int AccountConnectionIdDto { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateDto { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDateDto { get; set; }
    public Guid IdentityIdDto { get; set; }
    public int AccountIdDto { get; set; }
    public AccountDto AccountDto { get; set; }
}
```

Removing the `Dto` from my model names, and it all works. I feel like the postifx isn't being recognized or utilized at all, am I doing it the correct way?

Comment: Don't :) I see no good reason to postfix your dtos that way.

Comment: Understood, this is just an example of where the postfix isn't working. I mean if we assume a legitimate use-case, then what - it still won't be working right?

Comment: Check the tests in the AM repo for working examples.